# N or AND in pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, speech

Can I say «n» instead «and»?

Example: I like apples n pears.

Comment: Not in formal writing. Informally, I've seen some contractions - [here's one with *n'*](http://www.jackandjillkids.com/).

Comment: I mean - pronunciation in usually speech, not in writing.

Comment: In formal speech, no.

Comment: No problem. Nevertheless, there *are* instances where the 'd' sound seems to be swallowed - e.g. "and then" can sound like "an then". But I'll leave this for the real linguists to properly explain.

Comment: People are getting confused because it's an informal spelling. I recommend editing the main body of your question to emphasize that you are only asking about pronunciation. In speech, pronouncing "and" as "n" is not remarkable, and this pronunciation exists in standard and formal speech, not only in informal speech.

Answer (score 1):

*And* is reduced in speech to a simple nasal, sometimes syllabic, usually assimilated to what follows.
The full pronunciation /ænd/ occurs only when stressed and emphatic.

So, yes, you can **say** N instead of AND. In formal **and** informal speech.
Just don't write it.

Answer (score 0):

The article "[Weakform Words and Contractions for the Advanced EFL User](http://www.yek.me.uk/wkfms.html)"  from the website of the linguist Jack Windsor Lewis actually recommends actively avoiding the use of /d/ in *and* in most contexts:

> 68. ***and* /ən/ eg /ɪn ən ˈaʊt / *in and out*.** [...]
> 69. There is another weakform of *and* /ənd/ which has in some EFL textbooks been prescribed for use before words beginning with vowel sounds. In fact the weakform without /d/ occurs at least ten times as often as this form and therefore such a recommendation is misguided. It is far better for the EFL user to aim exclusively at weakforms without any /d/. Most English speakers make little or no use of /-d/ forms. Their chief occurrence is in hesitant or obtrusively careful speech. They can even sound quite misleading as when *Joe and Ann* is pronounced in a fashion that could be taken for *Joe and Dan*, a mistake which would not normally occur. One somewhat over careful but otherwise excellent former BBC newsreader used to seem to be talking not of *England and Wales* but of *England and Dwales*. She  seemed on occasion to refer to hospital A and D (meaning Accident & Emergency) departments. [...]
> 70. The strongform /ænd/ and the slightly reduced weakform /æn/ are often used sentence-initially but usually with a fairly marked deliberate or hesitant effect unless quickly uttered, eg /æn(d) rɪˈmembə/ *And remember...,* /æn(d) əˈnʌðə θɪŋ/ *And another thing...*
>       It's particularly worthwhile for the EFL user to attempt to acquire a natural-sounding use of the word *and* because it is, at approximately one percent of all word occurrences, about the most frequently used word in the English language. It sounds particularly strange to use its strongform between the constituent words of common collocations like *fish and chips, fits and starts, flesh and blood, hide and seek, odds and ends, smash and grab, so-and-so* (usually /ˈsəʊnsəʊ) and *try and* before a verb.

Of course, spellings like *n/n'/'n'* are markedly colloquial, and are rarely encountered outside of stylized proper names. Like many words, *and* has a standard spelling that does not correspond to its most common pronunciation.

Answer (score -2):

Not if you want to be formally correct in speech, no.

In spoken English, some dialects/accents have a tendency to merge together sounds, and so you move between the sounds of:

> Apples and pears
>
> Apples an' pears
>
> Apples 'n' pears

... but the word remains *and*. If you were writing to convey a particular style of speech, then you could use the above forms to represents the accent of that character. However, for your own speech... well, you could use those forms in spoken language, but whether that's successful depends very much on your own accent - you could just sound strange, rather like saying *Noo Joisey* because you want to sound like a local when you're actually nothing of the sort.

If it's normal in your accent, then it would be acceptable, as would everything else in your accent because... well, because it's your accent.

Comment: @sumelic Not my intention - the opening was about spoken, and the writing pieces were meant as background context. Edited.

Comment: OK. In that case, I disagree that pronunciations that elide the /d/ are not "formally correct."

Comment: I don't have a great reference at the moment, but consider the transcriptions here, which are presumably not meant to be informal or incorrect: http://www.multimedia-english.com/phonetics/weak-vs-strong-forms

Comment: If you say *Joisey* in New Jersey, you are giving away the fact that you are ***not*** a local. The *bird→boyd* aspect of the Noo Yawk City accent is totally dead, except maybe among Brooklyn octagenerians.

Comment: Well, we're clearly going to disagree and the downvotes will keep coming. But I stand by my comment: whether the OP can use the elided form depends on his accent: I know many non-native speakers who just sound odd when they try to use "native" pronunciation, because it isn't *their* native pronunciation. It has to be in context.