# Should we pronounce "T" in Won't?

Tags: pronunciation, speech

I have noticed that some native English speakers do not pronounce the "T" in "won't" in the middle of a sentence.  For example:

> I won't make you happy

sounds like:

> I wo make you happy

Is this correct ?

Comment: [Incredibly closely related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/399659/2085). Also see https://english.stackexchange.com/a/96584 https://english.stackexchange.com/a/327874

Comment: Similar to how *want to* devolved to *wanna*

Comment: It's a real pleasure to imagine Joey Ramone singing, ever so distinctly, "Twenty-, twenty-, twenty-four hours to go, I want to be sedated." Of the ten instances of _t_ in those words, I believe that Joey pronounces four of them with an actual "t" sound.

Comment: We pronounce it. Maybe not with a [t] sound, but we don't say *I wo make you happy*.

Answer (score -1):

I am from Montana. As far as I am aware, the T in "won't" is meant to be pronounced.

```
 The sentence you provided as an example is incorrectly pronounced.
```

Citation:
http://speakspeak.com/resources/pronunciation/pronunciation-difference-wont-want

Comment: add a citation to support your answer if you please.

Comment: http://speakspeak.com/resources/pronunciation/pronunciation-difference-wont-want

Comment: good ... now edit your answer ant put your citation in it.

Comment: I did that upon reading your latest comment... Thanks for the help.